# Regex para substituição

Tags: xml, regex

Bom dia.
Tenho um XML que contém um nó da seguinte forma:

```
 <endnum>76 AP 10 404</endnum>
 <endnum>404</endnum>
```

Acontece que esse valor deveria ser apenas inteiro, como no segundo exemplo, mas alguns contém letras.
Gostaria de localizar todos os nós desse campo que contém letra para substituir por `<endnum>0</endnum>.`
Tentei utilizar Regex e não fui feliz.
Algém saberia me indicar uma solução?

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que valores válidos só possuem números, você precisa só procurar pela existência de não-dígitos (`\D`) dentro dessa tag: `<endnum>.*?\D.*?<\/endnum>`. Depois é só colocar as tags em grupos de captura: `(<endnum>).*?\D.*?(<\/endnum>)` e substituir por `$10$2`.